# Как хранить время Unix формата в базе данных

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Получаю по api время в Unix формате 1639221460506, оно равно моему времени UTC+3

Как лучше всего его хранить в базе данных чтобы в последствии его использовать в `php` и в `js`?

Точнее вопрос в том переводить его в UTC+0 или на выводе конвертировать в то время которое у пользователя?

К примеру у пользователя UTC+4 то к 1639221460506 прибавлять UTC+1?

Comment: Время в Unix формате **одинаково** во всех местах на планете. И в UTC+3, и в UTC+2 и в UTC-4 количество секунд с начала юникс-эпохи __одинаково__.

Comment: @u_mulder то есть так лучше и хранить его в базе? мне самое главное чтобы вне какое у пользователя время всегда правильная дата отображалась

Comment: Ну да, а затем форматировать с учетом временной зоны пользователя который на это время смотрит.

Comment: а что случится с выводом если наступит дата 19 января 2038 года в 03:14:08 ?

Comment: Я думаю к тому времени все компьютеры станут минимум 64-битными.

Comment: Идеальный вариант вам не подскажут, т.к. вопрос сильно зависит от бизнеса и от того, что в дальнейшем вы планируете делать с этой датой, но, один из распространенных подходов, это перевести timestamp в mysql datetime по UTC (естественно +00:00), далее, для корректного отображения данных у юзера, модифицируете полученный datetime из базы в соответствии с часовым поясом пользователя. (Хотя вы можете хранить его и в +03:00, ничего не изменится, вам только нужно будет это где-то задокументировать и держать в голове при модификации datetime для клиента).